# What is the Big-O complexity of this code?

Tags: big-o, time-complexity

What would be the big O for

```
void fun(int n) {
   for(i=1; i<=n; i=i+2) { }
}
```

My answer: O(log n) (since the `i` values is 1,3,5,7,9 reducing by 2 overall)

```
void fun(int n) {
    for(i=1; i<=n; i=i+2) { }
}
```

My answer: O(log n), since this is quadratic (i think).

```
void fun (int n) {
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        for(j=1;j<=n;j++) { }

        for(k=1;k<=n;k++) { }
     }
}
```

My answer: O(n^3) since the loop has to go through exclusively one for `j` and `k` within `i`.

Please clarify.

Comment: Your first two examples appear to be identical.

Comment: On the second case, did you mean for (i = 1; i <= n; i=i*2)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formal definition of big-O notation is

> f(x) ∈ O(g(x)) as there exists c > 0 (e.g., c = 1) and x0 (e.g., x0 =
>   5) such that f(x) < cg(x) whenever x > x0.

From your thinking, it seems you don't understand that if there is a constant that can be multiplied by g(x) such that f(x) is always less than or equal to g(x), f(x) is not a greater order of magnitude than g(x).

Here are the big-O solutions:

(1) O(n).  O(n/2) is O(n)

(2) O(n) because this is the same as (1)

(3) O(n^2) because the inner loop runs 2 * n times for each iteration of the outer loop, which runs n times.  Thus the run is 2 * n * n which is O(n^2)

Answer (score 3):

1. O(n): even though incrementing by two halves the number of values that are processed, this is still **proportional to *n***. Compare these graphs of n, n/2, and log n:

   [image]

   You can see that n/2 remains proportional to n (always exactly half, i.e. it is off by a **constant factor**), while log n increases significantly more slowly.

   In big-O notation, **constant factors are ignored**, i.e. O(2n) = O(n), because 2 is insignificant compared to n when n is very large.
2. Assuming you probably meant `for(i=1;i<=n;`**`i=i*2`**`)` in your second example, this will in fact be O(log n), since you are inspecting exponentially increasing values (1, 2, 4, 8, 16, ...) so `i` will be doubled at most *log n* times before it reaches *n*. For example, if n = 16, `i` will be doubled 4 times (as in the example listed above), and *4 = log₂ 16*.
3. O(n²) since the inner loop runs 2n times, and the outer loop runs n times, so each inner loop iteration is O(n), so when this is run *n* times for the outer loops, the total complexity is O(n²).

Often, a quick way to estimate the time complexity of your code, if you have a number of nested loops, each from 0 to n (maybe with some constant factor), is to count how deep the loop nesting goes. Then, assuming each innermost loop iteration performs a *constant-time* operation (e.g. incrementing a number, accessing an array index), the total time complexity will be *n^k*, where *k* is the number of nested loops. This works for your example 3, that has 2 levels of loop nesting (even though the innermost level has two loops one after the other, this just adds a constant factor).

Answer (score 1):

The first one is O(n). Yes, you skip half of the loop cycles, but that means that for every n, you loop n/2 times and O(n/2) is the same as O(n).

The second one looks just like the first one, but I'm gonna assume you meant:

```
for (i = 1; i < n; i=i*2)

}
```

and yes, that's O(log n)

The third one can confuse you because it gives the impression of being a triple nested loop but it really isn't, the two inner loops are nested on the first one so it's really O(n*(n+n)) = O(n*2n) = O(2n^2) and that ends up being O(n^2)

Answer (score 0):

```
void fun(int n){
    for(i=1;i<=n;i=i+2){;}
}
```

An example loop:

```
i:    1   3   5   7   9   11   13   15   ...
```

> The loop iterates approximately n/2 times, which is in O(n).

---

```
void fun(int n){
    for(i=1;i<=n;i=i*2){;}
}
```

An example loop would go through:

```
i:    1   2   4   8   16   32   64   128   ...
```

> That is not quadratic. That is exponential. It loops
>   approximately log(n) times (to the base of 2, but it does not really
>   matter here), and thus it is in O(log(n)).

Quadratic (polynomial of degree 2) would be

```
i:    1   4   9   16  25   36  49  64  ...
```

Try to see the difference between those two, exponential starts slower, but grows faster the higher i grows.

---

```
void fun(int n){
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
        for(j=1;j<=n;j++){;} // O(n)
        for(k=1;k<=n;k++){;} // O(n)
    }
}
```

The two inner loops are both executed n times respectively, which is 2*n steps.

> The outer loop is executed n times. In each step the two inner loops
>   are executed. Which make in total n * 2 * n, which is in O(n^2).